# How do I move something downwards without it dissapearing off the form? VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

This is really quite ridiculous, but I have a picture box called picWeather, and it covers the whole form and looks like rain, and I want it to look like it's falling. This code does it perfectly, but goes up instead of down?!?!?!?!!?!

```
picWeather.Top = picWeather.Top - 50                    'Moves rain up by 50
picWeather.Height = picWeather.Height + 50              'Adds 50 to the height of the rain
If picWeather.Top < -10000 Then                         'If the rain is 10000 above the form then
    picWeather.Top = Me.Top                                 'Set the position of the top of the rain to the top of the form
    picWeather.Height = Me.Height                           'Set the height of the rain to the height of the form
End If                                                  'End the if statement
```

It's so simple, but because moving something by the bottom is read only and when you add height to something it adds it to the bottom, it's confusing... Anyone able to get there head around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Y coordinates are measured down from the top of the form. If you want to move something downward then you need to INCREASE the `Top` value, not DESCREASE it.

You should only be setting `Left`, `Top`, `Width` and `Height` if you only want to set one of them. If you want to set multiple then do one of the following:

- Set `Location` to set `Left` and `Top`.
- Set `Size` to set `Width` and `Height`.
- Set `Bounds` to set `Location` and `Size`.
- Call `SetBounds` to set any combination of `Left`, `Top`, `Width` and `Height`.

In your case, you want to set `Top` and `Height` so you should be calling `SetBounds`. That said, is there actually any point changing the `Height`? If you want the rain to initially cover the whole form and appear to be moving down then you need the `PictureBox` to have an initial `Height` that is greater then the form and a `Top` that is less than zero. As you move the `PictureBox` down, the `Top` approaches zero and you can reset when it gets there, e.g.

```vb
If picWeather.Top = 0 Then
    'Move the rain back up to its starting position.
    picWeather.Top = -10000
Else
    'Move the rain down 50 pixels.
    picWeather.Top += 50
End If
```

As a physical analogy, let's say that you are looking through a window at a picture that I'm holding. The picture is much taller than the window. I start by positioning the picture such that its bottom edge lines up with the bottom edge of the window. I slowly move it down and you see "rain falling". When the top of the picture gets level with the top of the window, I quickly move picture back up to its starting position. That's exactly what that code does: it moves the control down by increasing the `Top` value and then, when the top edge lines up with the top edge of the form, it immediately the control back to its starting position with its top edge well above that of the form.

Comment: :D Thanks, how many of my problems have you sold now?!?!?

Comment: Solved not sold